# Why Visual Studio doesn't create a public class by default?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio when you add a new class, it always created with no modifiers and that makes class internal.

```
class MyClass
{
}
```

I would prefer that my class by default is created as public one.

Why is it internal by default?

What would you prefer?

Comment: If you want to modify the default behavior, check out this question/answer... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Now if only it was sealed per default as well it would be perfect.

Comment: But be consciously aware of the potential implications of this...

Comment: The only implication is that new classes will be public...

Comment: This is not a duplicate question to the one marked.  This question specifically asks why, not how to change it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Making class `internal` by default makes perfect sense to me: keep your privates to yourself and only explicitly expose parts which really need to be exposed: everything else is just implementation details and should not be visible to the outside world.

In case you want to test your `internal` classes, .NET 2.0 onwards introduces a new attribute called [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx), which

> Specifies that types that are ordinarily visible only within the current assembly are visible to another assembly.

If this really annoys you, see `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7 IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\Class.zip`. This is a template which you can change to suit your needs. ReSharper has similar capability, but it's directly accessible from within th UI.

Comment: ReSharper by default creates public class.  And that makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: You can use InternalsVisbleToAttribute only with strong-signed assemblies.

Comment: Anton,  can you be more specific.  It's not going to be the first time I'm wrong.  I just want to know what I'm wrong about.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry. See this page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx ) for more info on this attribute.

Comment: The path is slightly different for VS 2010, it is in "Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033" (notice additional Code folder). Also it probably makes sense to modify the Interface template in the same folder.

Comment: For VS 2017 path is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs"`

Comment: Correct path for VS 2017 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class`

Comment: I had all of the paths above and none of them worked. I finally found another visual studio directory for VS Pro.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class

Comment: Defaulting to `internal` makes sense when developing a re-usable package, however it does not make sense in application code, especially when solution structure is divided into infrastructure/domain/application layers. In such cases most of the classes need to be accessible in other assemblies.

Answer (score 80):

To create a Public class by default for Visual Studio 2012:

Edit this file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs`

(Visual Studio 2022: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class`)

To look like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

More info: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/05/edit-default-visual-studio-2012-item.html

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class

Answer (score 9):

C# tends to default everything to the minimum scope necessary. This is a nice convention and quoted in Skeet's book ([C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), p 224 "Note/Trivia"):

> *[Properties are the] only place where “private” is required*—Everywhere else in C#, the
>   default access modifier in any given situation is the most private one possible. In other words, if something can be declared to be private, then leaving out the access modifiers entirely will default it to being private. This is a nice element of language design, because it’s hard to get it wrong accidentally: if you want something to be more public than it is, you’ll notice when you try to use it.

Comment: Actually, classes are internal by default. Class members are private.

Comment: Try to create a class an look at with Reflector.

Comment: Joe is correct. Classes *can't* be private (unless they're nested within other types), though their members by default are.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks for the explanation--a private class wouldn't make a lot of sense

Comment: In C#, A class is Internal by default, unless it's a nested class

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, your updated answer is fine now. The minimum scope convention is a useful one to keep in mind.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer it the way it is.  This way you have to consciously decide that you want it exposed to public.  It's much like the argument, do you want your computer open to the outside world by default or would you rather configure it for internet access yourself.

Both approaches have their advantages, one has major potential security implications that I believe you should be aware of and make a conscious decision about rather than just it just happening automatically.

Comment: Good argument, in my opinion. Opt-in public exposure is preferable over opt-out.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly this only happens in C# - in vb.net you get a Public Class by default.

Personally, i prefer a public class by default as generally other classes need access to it. (most of my work is in the data layer though)

Comment: Do other classes outside your assembly really need access to most of your classes? I doubt it, but if so, you should reconsider how you group classes into assemblies! C# defaults to internal, where all classes in the same assembly have access.

Answer (score 2):

Because in C#, a class is internal by default. VisualStudio is therefore following the C# specification.

The following article explains access modifiers and default visibility in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could change the templates for a C# class - Usually located in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#"

or even create your own template.

Comment: sarnath'd - personally I like to be prompted with an actual keyword, but 99% of the time my classes are public anyway. Hmm, maybe that's a design smell...

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer it as is, It forces you to actively think which classes you want to make public.

It ultimately defaults you into a hopefully cleaner API design and hence better more friendly software. You wouldn't want to expose the inner workings of your code, which would inevitably happen if everything defaulted to public.

This is somewhat subjective, personally I prefer everything to off and turn on only what I need not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice in all areas of code to keep things as restricted as possible. Without specific reason for being otherwise, everything should be private, readonly (better yet const), and static. If a variable, method, or property can be private, make it private. If it can't be private, but can be protected, make it protected. If it can be readonly, make it readonly. If it can be static, make it static. The same is true for classes: they should be internal by default, and made public only when you have decided that this is a class you wish to export.