# Why does visual studio set the access modifier of a new class to internal

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Using visual studio to create a windows form application. There are multiple projects contained in this solution, with each project having multiple folders. When i use the context menu in the solution explorer to add/create a new class inside of a folder, it set the access modifier to internal.

```
namespace Namespace.Name
{
    internal class ClassName
    {
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is the default in this case?

Comment: This is just Visual Studio being "explicit". If it wasn't there.. it would mean the same thing (as per the answer below).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824555/why-visual-studio-doesnt-create-a-public-class-by-default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this is the *default* access modifier for a class, which is not nested. For further documenation on this, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).