# How to change default access modifer added by CodeMaid

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, codemaid

I am using the Visual Studio CodeMaid plugin currently and when I press `Ctrl`+`m`+`space` to cleanup my active document it adds a default access modifier of `internal` to my class/interface/etc.. I've looked through the options to change it to be `public`, but haven't had any luck. Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most member types:

> `internal` is the default if no access modifier is specified.
>   [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

CodeMaid has the option to explicitly specify the access modifier in order to reduce the chance for developer confusion.  You can disable this behavior at CodeMaid->Options->Cleaning->Insert->"Insert explicit access modifiers for" and toggle individual member types (e.g. classes, properties, etc.)

If you want to change something from its default `internal` to `public`, you will need to explicitly add the `public` access modifier.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when you say "from its default internal to public, you will need to explicitly add the public access modifier." you mean manually removing `internal` and typing out `public` right?

Comment: Yes, or typing in `public` before invoking CodeMaid.  If an access modifier is already specified, CodeMaid won't add the default.

Comment: A workaround is to edit the Visual Studio class template, and add the public modifier there. As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781044/552294