# Change visual studio defaul to public, instead of internal

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, internals

So, I understand why people prefer internal by default. Good for them. But my code must BE testable. and Internal leaves me with less options to test my code or requiring me to write boilerplate access bridges to allow my code to be tested. Everytime I create a method, is set to internal. I am tired. I am tired of changing them to public. So, I want this:

- When I create visual studio field/property. I want such field or property to be public by default.
- When I create visual studio class, I want it to be public by default, until i choose it to be private (I never use internal btw. Either private or public)

I find internal a terrible code smell and breaks OOP. (Either an object exposes its behaviour or it doesn't)

How can I force visual studio to do that?

Comment: Check at this answer, it worked for me in Visual Studio 2022
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781044/15496750