# Setting to explicitly write default access modifier in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

When I generate a new class, I would like to have the default access modifier written down explicitly like:

```
internal class Foo
{
}
```

instead of:

```
class Foo
{
}
```

Is that possible with a setting and if so - how?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos At namespace scope there is no `private`. But you are correct for member types.

Comment: @Richard hmmm, I can't remember encountering `internal class` until now

Comment: related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things you can do:

1. Modify the class file template. This is found in you VS installation:

   ```
   <InstallRoot>\<Edition>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class
   ```
2. To confirm something has been specified: add the following to a `.editorconfig`:

   ```
   dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers=always:suggestion
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I really like editorconfig here is how you create one automatically:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2019
manually: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by editing the snippets of Class of your installed visual studio.

- Press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+B a code snippets manager will open
- navigate to the location present in location text filed and edit the file with name class.snippet in text editor and change line
  [image]

> ```
> <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[ class $name$
>           {
>               $selected$$end$
>           }]]>
>                   </Code>
> ```

to

> ```
>   <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[internal  class $name$
>       {
>           $selected$$end$
>       }]]>
>               </Code>
> ```

Comment: I was so confident it would work, I was totally suprised it didn't. Even restart of VS, adding the folder again and Import did not help. Any ideas? (thank you so far!)

Comment: Yes - as you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code Snippet to do that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019)

> Code snippets are small blocks of reusable code that can be inserted
>   in a code file using a right-click menu (context menu) command or a
>   combination of hotkeys. They typically contain commonly used code
>   blocks such as try-finally or if-else blocks, but they can be used to
>   insert entire classes or methods.