# Problem with creating a C# class from template in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, class, interface, visual-studio-2022

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio 2022. After using template to create a class/interface the code is generated with an error. There is no whitespace between "internal" and "class". The problem is hapenning with one particular project. When I createad a file in a new project the problem did't occur. Did anyone experience this issue as well and has a solution?

[Screenshot - "internalclass"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HVws.png)

**EDIT:**

Fixed using solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio).

Comment: Does this help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates?view=vs-2022 ?

Comment: Haven't experienced that issue, although I've followed the article Paul gave to change mine to use the public access modifier anyway (I tend to use a lot cross-project interfaces).

Comment: Each of the folders in the location %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Templates\ProjectTemplates is empty, therefore I can't modify any. I'll try to create a new template, maybe that will help.

Comment: The issue is only happening in the particular project. When created a new project the problem was gone.