# Visual Studio adds unnecessary using's when creating a new class

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I use Visual Studio 2022 to work with .Net stack.
When I am creating a new class or interface it always appears with a bunch of unnecessary using's.

Is it possible to disable such behavior?

[image]

Comment: @julealgon OP is asking about the redundant using directives at the head of the file not the class's accessibility. However that answer does provide a way to do what OP asks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer to [How do you default a new class to public when creating it in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700086/how-do-you-default-a-new-class-to-public-when-creating-it-in-visual-studio) it is possible to edit templates  Visual Studio uses for the new Classes and Interfaces.

For VS2022 Community Edition the path to templates folder is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\`

Thanks [julealgon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946412/julealgon) for the hint